# JasperReports missing text in pdf export

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm working with JasperReports a few weeks. I'm exporting an report in HTML, DOCX and PDF format.

The DOCX and HTML report looks fine but in PDF sometimes the text in a textElement is truncated.

[image]

Maybe someone can help me?

Here ist the jrxml code for this textElement:

```
<detail>
    <band height="29" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="260" y="0" width="284" height="29" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="602856c9-7bf6-481d-a9f9-449498ff5168">
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" spacingBefore="3" spacingAfter="3"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TEXT}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="110" y="0" width="140" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="4c12bb30-f160-42ba-a6a1-60f0f9832732">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                <paragraph spacingBefore="3" spacingAfter="3"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="60" y="0" width="50" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="f3242a8a-555e-451a-84c6-9cb1e9e5654b">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                <paragraph spacingBefore="3" spacingAfter="3"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["[".concat(String.format("%03d", $F{BT})).concat("]")]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

I added also the fonts and the jasperreports_extension.properties
Here is the jasperreports_extension.properties:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy=true
net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text=true
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding=Identity-H
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.myfamily=/fonts/myfamily.xml
```

The property

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy=true
```

has no effect to my pdf file.

Here this the code from the java class where i create the PDF (notice this is not the complete code):

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = new JasperPrint();

this.getDataForReport();

JRResultSetDataSource rsDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(this.resultSetReport);

JRDataSource jrData = rsDataSource;

HashMap<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();

JasperReport jasperReportMain = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(ReportsConfiguration
        .getTemplatePath() + "report.jrxml");

jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReportMain, param, jrData);

JRPdfExporter exporterPDF = new JRPdfExporter();

exporterPDF.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
File exportReportFilePdf = new File(fileNamePdf);
exporterPDF.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(exportReportFilePdf));
exporterPDF.exportReport();
```

Comment: i'm using jasperreport-6.2.2 with commons-beanutils-1.8.2, commons-collections-3.2.1, commons-digester-2.1, commons-logging-1.1, groovy-all-2.0.1, itext-2.1.7.js4-20150903.153643-1, jasperreports-fonts-6.2.2, jasperreports-functions-6.2.2, jasperreports-javaflow-6.2.2, jdt-compiler-3.1.1, jfreechart-1.0.12, joda-time-2.1, poi-3.7-20101029

Comment: `PDF sometimes the text in a textElement is truncated` - Could you post the image? What do you mean "sometimes"?

Comment: unfortunately i cannot post a picture of the report. But the length of the text in the textElement TEXT is dynamic. An example: in DOCX is the length 80 (same length in the source) and in PDF only 65. With "sometimes" i meen that i cannot find any pattern (maybe the text is truncated because some special charakters or something like that - but it's not)

Comment: when i set the height of the textElement bigger, the text is not truncated (but i don't know the max height for the textElement). But this cannot be the solution...the space between the textElement (vertical) is disturbing

Comment: Here is an example.           http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160718/biympjgt.png    i hope this helps

Comment: Has nobody any idea?

Comment: If solved the problem: when i use java 1.8 the pdf report looks great. (before is used 1.7)

Comment: You can add this comment as an answer to the question.

Comment: Where did you change the java version?